# Java: sync method how to synchronized with sync static method?

Tags: java, multithreading

Code Snippet:

```
public class SyncTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SyncTest().test();
}

private void test() {
    final Outputer outputer = new Outputer();

    // Thread 1
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                outputer.outPut("一二三四五六七八九");
            }
        }
    }).start();

    // Thread2
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Outputer.outPut2("123456789");  
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

static class Outputer {
    public void outPut( String name) {          
        int len = name.length();
        synchronized (Outputer.this) {                          // lock is Outputer.class
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static synchronized void outPut3( String name) {     // lock also is Outputer.class
        int len = name.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

**Output** :

123456789
1一2二三四五六七八九
3456789

obvious no synchronized, please give a hand, thanks

Comment: `synchronized` does not specify order. It's up to the thread scheduler.

Comment: The code you posted works for me without any synchronization problems.

Comment: please try more times, and scrolled to the top ouput,you will find the problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the class instance instead of `this`, so both use the same Monitor object

```
static class Outputer {
    public void outPut( String name) {          
        int len = name.length();
        synchronized (Outputer.class) {      // Outputer.this is not the same as Outputer.class
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

alternatively you can use a seperate monitor object so thats explicit which will be used:

```
static class Outputer {
    private static Object syncronisationMonitor = new Object();

    // nonstatic method
    public void outPut( String name) {          
        synchronized (syncronisationMonitor ) { // we use the same monitor as in the static method                        
           [...]
        }
    }

    //static method
    public static void outPut3( String name) {    
        synchronized (syncronisationMonitor ) {  // we use the same monitor as in the non-static method                                               
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd additionally suggest marking `syncronisationMonitor` as `final`.

Comment: thats true, I forgot... you see thread handling and syncronisation is very delicate

Comment: // Outputer.this is not the same as Outputer.class ? I'm sorry, don‘t quite understand

Comment: `Outputer.this` is the same as `this`, a references of the current Object instance. `Outputer.class` is an object of the type `Class<?>` representing the class `Outputer`